# Trying to pull files from mapped network drive Python

Tags: python, directory, pull, drive

I am trying to pull folder names from a network drive in Python. For example, if I have a mapped drive U:, I want to go through and grab all the folders in folder "example" from the path `\emily\hello\example`.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
import os
os.chdir('U:')
all_subdirs = [d for d in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(d)]
for dirs in all_subdirs:
    dir = os.path.join('\emily\hello\example', dirs)
    os.chdir(dir)
    current = os.getcwd()
    new = str(current).split("\")[4]
    print(new)
```

this causes many errors, and I am having an issue with the syntax of a shared drive on the network vs a folder locally on my computer.

I want to see them in a list so i can read line  by line and compare this list to another list.

ps. i don't want the files in the folders, just the folder names in the folder

thanks~!

error message is C:\Users\212582086\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/212582086/Desktop/Vendor sort/main"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/212582086/Desktop/Vendor sort/main", line 6, in 
    os.chdir(dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\emily\hello\example\Software Archive'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Can you include the error message and traceback? It's not clear from your question what goes wrong here.

Comment: C:\Users\212582086\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:/Users/212582086/Desktop/Vendor sort/main"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/212582086/Desktop/Vendor sort/main", line 6, in <module>
    os.chdir(dir)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\emily\\hello\\example\\Software Archive'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What is the expected outcome here? There seems to be a directory on drive U called `U:\Software Archive\ `. But there's no directory with the name `\emily\hello\example\Software Archive\ `. `os.chdir()` fails when you pass it the name of a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: how do you format it though? regardless of exisiting or not... i don't understand. if i am in a U drive and it has a link or somthing with folders, how would i put it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how do you format it". You can't open a directory that doesn't exist. If you tell us what you expect the code to do, we can suggest how to fix it.

Comment: i understand. my code now works. all that i don't understand how to do is find the path there. when i say format, i mean do i write it like 'c:/desktop/emily/example' or the backslashes? or if it's not on the computer, and on a network drive, do i have to inlude the link there? for example: if i hvae a file that looks like data(\\example03.fsr.read.com)(U:) and there are folders in there named \emily\example  and i want to read all of the folders in example

Comment: Python is quite liberal with path names in windows. You can use forward slashes instead of backslash. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: i figured it out. i apologize! i stink at explaining things :) what i was wondering if i had to include the .com link part before the drive letter, but i didn't have to. just the drive letter with the location.